# Specific EditText Android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm new at Android, and almost haven't any work with `EditText` view, but still i received image with some `EditText` that i must use.

[image: Image Received with som EditText]


I saw some similar `EditText` in custom dialog from [official Android developer page (Figure 5)](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html). 


 As you can see, there are some underlines, in each EditText.


 First i thought, that `EditText`, with such underline, is default View. But when i tried to make such EditText component, i faced problem, that default `EditText` haven't any underlines, and it's just a simple rectangle, without any images inside... I tried to make this component another background (creating selector xml file), setting some background image... Nothing works.


 Please, give me advice: How to make such EditBox with underline, and that image above that `EditText`.


 P.S. I'm using 10 API Level (2.3.3) with support library to work with fragments.


 P.S.S. Sorry for little information. I'm new at Stackoverflow, and can't post Images, and more than 2 Hyperlinks...

Comment: You should have no problems making a custom background for your `EditText`. Show us what you tried in that direction

Comment: Welcome to SO. Don't worry about restrictions as a new user, we all have faced them. But, as K-ballo commented, any time that you can post some relevant code and any logcat or other error messages you may have, it makes getting help a lot easier and faster.

Comment: I'm using identical layout values for my EditText, as that example from official site, but still they have that underline, without setting any background value and i haven't.

Comment: I can't insert any code from my xml file with layout of this EditBox, need to know better SO. But still that code is right at that Figure 5, from link i gave. Please look there, my code is realy identical, it was copy-paste and no underline. I'm not realy interested in background color, but in that line, and i don't want to insert image for backgroud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a higher API Level and your EditText will look like that by default (given you are using the theme for it.  Try to load your application in with API level 4.0 (14) or 4.0.3 (15) and take a look.

Also, check out [**this site**](http://androiddrawables.com/) (specifically [**this**](http://androiddrawables.com/widget.html) for widgets).  You can get a sense of what graphics and backgrounds are used. You should be able to download and apply these backgrounds using basic styling techniques without major difficulty.

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong. I must download nine-patch image, and set is as background or smth?

Comment: Yes. There are many tutorials on creating custom EditTexts online.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem!

As [burmat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14250053/104223) told me, I created some nine-patch image with a simple orange underline.
Then I inserted my `EditText` in a Relative Layout. Then inserted the image I needed.

The result was exactly what I wanted!